# Math behind neodymium ball magnet toys?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Is there some theory behind [zen magnets/buckyball-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neodymium_magnet_toys) toys?
[image: example form]
Did somebody study what forms you can make out of N magnets? Will given form be stable and not be teared apart by magnetic force? How to construct a form closest to given free-form model?
I am searching for a theory which can answer to questions above and similar.

Comment: See [**sphere packing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing)

Comment: Yeah, I have seen that. But it does not describe fully behaviour of this toy. For example some of arrangements permitted by sphere packing are not allowed because of magnetic properties. Are there some studies to describe such constraints?